# How to create checkbox options for executing functions in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

In my extension i have a file `background.js`, which starts with clicking on the extension icon and runs the following code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "functions.js"})
});
```

The file `functions.js` contains three different `window.open` functions, which are executed immediately after `background.js` calls `functions.js`. Working scenario: user clicks on the extension icon - three new tabs are open.

---

I want to add a checkbox selection, to select, which function(s) will be executed. It should work anyhow like:

- After click on the extension icon small popup opens. It contains three checkboxes and a button *Run*.
- Checking of a checkbox selects a function from `functions.js`, which will executed after clicking on the button *Run*.

What is the approach to do this?

Comment: Instead of onClicked you'll need to [declare the popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) in manifest.json, see also [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) that use "popup.html". The page should load a script file, this file will run every time the popup is shown.

Comment: @wOxxOm Cool links - thank you! Will dig deeper and come back.